# Domain name cannot be resolved / Nameserver issue?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, domain

I am trying to setup a small Wordpress website, hosted on Vultr (Ubuntu w/ preinstalled Wordpress), having registered my domain name from Godaddy. What I usually do, when pointing to a hosting server, is I just change the A record on my DNS settings to point to my server IP, and it worked the first time. But we had some software issue with the server and decided to scrap it and spin up a new instance.

But this time I had a friend do the DNS remapping, who migrated all the default nameservers to Vultr nameservers, having deleted the original DNS records from Godaddy. But I somehow managed to switch back to the default Godaddy nameservers and have added an A record pointing to the server IP and a CNAME www record that points to my domain name (besides the default records that specify the 2 NS and the SOA record).

### The issue:

1. It has been 36 hours since I changed my domain nameservers to the default Godaddy NS but I keep getting `Temporary failure in name resolution` whenever I try to ping it from my main workstation connected to my home network, even on different browsers.
2. I am having no issues pinging or opening the site using my mobile network. Even the customer service guys at Godaddy can view our website, but neither me nor my friend can open it.
3. I tried tracking the propagation at dnsmap.io and dnschecker and we keep getting unresolved at the same places as it were when we changed it back.

I am having a hard time figuring out what I am doing wrong, and I am asking for guidance. I am extremely sorry if this a noob question, but I am losing patience fast.

Comment: I would have made WWW an A record, but I guess your way will work. You need to look at your DNS server and see why it cant resolve it. Are you familiar with NSLOOKUP ?Run nslookup from a command prompt and it will tell you right away what server it is using. enter your hostname and it will call your DNS server to look it up. If you cant resolve the name it means Your DNS server cant figure it out. switch to Google DNS by entering "server 8.8.8.8" then enter your hostname again. If google can find it then you need to find out why your current DNS server cant.  Play around with nslookup.

Comment: Hi, thanks for volunteering to help me out, really appreciate it. It seems that google public dns cannot resolve the site. I have run a small list of commands and added it to pastebin (by throwing security out the window), for your perusal: https://pastebin.com/5Epcjh6i

Comment: Okay, so after tearing my hair out for quite a while, I figured and fixed the problem: It was because of a bad DNSEC digest. Sorry for bothering everyone. Also thank you @Larryc This question can now be closed.

Comment: Excellent, glad you found it.